# API Creation for Square Matrix Using .Net

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-core

I am working on creating a API in .net core to implement a square matrix. For simplicity take the below matrix with rows and columns A,B, C and D. Rows and columns are same A,B,C,D and value in square matrix is Y or N. A,B,C,D have some priorities i.e. 1,2,3,4 and some value like amount say 20,40,30,10. Now the ask is when we input the API any combination of the value of A,B,C,D say A+B+D we want the possible combination based on Y and N and which ever combination  is giving highest total.

Like For A,B,D A will only be Applied alone and B and D will be another combination. A- 20 and B+D is 50 so the output should be B,D.

|  | A | B | C. | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Cell Y | Cell N | Y | N |
| B | Cell N | Cell Y | N | Y |
| C | Cell Y | Cell N | Y | N |
| D | Cell N | Cell Y | N | Y |

I tried to expand the Matrix by creating different combinations but due to the large square matrix the data is getting too large.

Comment: Might be but needs to be implemented programmatically. It is done manually right now but the requirement is for a tool or Api in .net.

Comment: That is not helpful, no one is saying that I am hiring you to solve this problem. I have that problem and this is the platform for asking that problem. If you don't have anything to add for that then do not reply.